# accessing b2Fixture

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have two classes for sprites and would like to access the b2Fixture of the sprites in the HelloWorldLayer.mm. What is the most appropriate way to access these properties? I plan to create a weld joint between them on contact. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one or more fixtures on the bodies at the time you create them. Then you can use

```
 b2Body *body = world->GetBodyList();
 b2Fixture *fixture = body->GetFixtureList();
```

You might also want to know what type of body you're dealing with, for which you can use the `body->GetUserData()` method. Refer to the manual for more info. http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082972